# Passing data to SignalR Hub using Post method to Web Api returned: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, signalr

Recently, I just started to learn on SignalR and I had been testing on one [project](https://github.com/stevehobbsdev/blog-wcfcpuapp) that I found on GitHub. However I did stuck when trying to Post data to Web api part.

I just get everything done yet I cannot really make this project to work somehow. This is basically the program for the project. It is a console app and did send the data(Json) to Web Api

```
    // Get the stuff we need to send
    GetMetrics(out cpuTime, out memUsage, out totalMemory);

    // Send the data
    var postData = new
    {
       MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName,
       Processor = cpuTime,
       MemUsage = memUsage,
       TotalMemory = totalMemory
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

    // Post the data to the server http://localhost:80/api/cpuinfo
    var serverUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUrl"]);

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.UploadString(serverUrl, json);
```

Moving to web part. I did have the Asp.net MVC and did create the RouteConfig inside the App_Start to route HTTP request to controller.

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And this is the controller class.

```
    public class CpuInfoController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(CpuInfoPostData cpuInfo)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CpuInfo>();
        context.Clients.All.cpuInfoMessage(cpuInfo.MachineName, cpuInfo.Processor, cpuInfo.MemUsage, cpuInfo.TotalMemory);
    }
}
```

I also had it registered inside Global.asax as below

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

After done all this, I still cant get this done and my console application pop up some errors as in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1l8L.png). It seems like the **api/cpuinfo** was not found.

Please advice me if anything that I had done wrong here.
The full version of this project can be found [here](https://github.com/stevehobbsdev/blog-wcfcpuapp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the File App.config in "CpuInfoClient" project. (the value of the Key)

1. Use "http" instead of "https"
2. Change the port number to the actual port number (instead of 44300), that uses the web application  after starting. The exact port for the substitution you can see , when the web app starts in IE or Firefox. The port is also in "WcfCpuApp -> Properties -> Web -> Project-URL
3. Be sure that your web application is running, when you start "CpuInfoClient"